# Database or FileSystem , which one is faster ?

Tags: php, mysql

Im working on Blog based Website having more than 50k posts. I need suggestions to increase the website speed.

I have two options

1: I can pick up the post data from the mysql database and display it using php

2: Static Webpage for each post (Using DOM parser i can Update the Post Contents)

which one is fast database or File System ? or any other suggestions to speedup my website.Im using go daddy shared hosting.

Comment: Depends: Whats making it "slow" now? as a whole processing pages each time to display the same thing would make them slower, so "caching them" and generating static pages for the page would technically be faster, as the page is then just straight text to dump, no db connection etc.

Comment: Depends on the website. In long term, you'l regret for not chosing database if it grows bigger and bigger. For small size sites, it can work without database but certainly i won't prefer it then.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

1. a `pagination` for the site.
2. implement coding style: `fetch-what-you-only-need` from the database
3. run some load tests on where on your site needs improving.

Comment: Especially the third point is a good suggestion. First find out what is the thing that makes your site slow, then improve that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, looked up godaddy and they do not allow memcached :(

<strike>Use database and implement [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to cache recently shown pages.</strike>

Even with 50 K posts I imagine that most fetches are for a small subset of posts for a specific time period, usually recent posts.

If this is the case a memcache solution would beat any disk based storage.

Automatically generating static pages for posts for often retrieved posts is another way.

But base storage in a database is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get reliable performance on shared hosting, so just go with what's easiest to work with. Today you may get fast access to the file system, but tomorrow they relocate your app to another silo and the database becomes faster. It's a lot easier to extend a database to add new features, so I'd go with that.

But if you really care about performance you have to make tests to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use page caching for whole page
2. query caching from caching results of database queries

   using file system will give only give trouble in update ,delete ,insert etc..